# How to join a windows server domain

Tags: networking

Could youy help me with Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop in join a windows server 2008 domain.  I have tried google this problem but none of them work.  I was not able to get likewise to work.  I am very new at Linux Ubuntu I need all the help I can get to do this. Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop PC to join a windows server 2008 domain and be able to login with AD and map network drives from the window server. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You've to install smb protocol first:

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

and configure it :
[Samba server on Ubuntu](https://www.howtoforge.com/samba-server-ubuntu-14.10)

And enjoy!